# react native picker - doesn't hide when android back button pressed

Tags: android, react-native, picker, stack-navigator

I have a listener on the whole app for the back button press event in android to override the default behaviour of back button(exit the app).
Also in some component i have override it too if i want the back button to be disabled or do something else.
The problem is when i open a react-native-picker, the picker stays on the screen ignoring the back button press.

I want it to first close (on the first back button press) and only then do what the higher component ordered to do when back button is pressed.
so i can't override the the higher component back button handling

i thought maybe to add the picker as a screen in the navigator and instead of planting it as a component, navigate to it, so it will be added to the stack navigator.
then by default it will first pop it of the stack when pressing back.

how can i add the picker component as a screen to navigate to, or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I didnt get the package you are using? is it Picker of react-native? or react-native-picker/picker?

Comment: react-native-picker - this is what is in the package.json, i didn't know there are two options

Answer (score 0):

By default the back behavior collapses or closes the picker on Android (depending on the mode you have chosen). You can see a working example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@tnr_c/hadaspicker).

Comment: this is not the picker i use, i use the react-native-picker and it doesn't have "mode" option and it's default is not to collapse

Comment: You mean this package: https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker?

Comment: If so the same applies and works. I've tried.

Comment: https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select
this one, i'll try to switch to the one you mentioned

Comment: The package you referenced has a working example: https://snack.expo.dev/@lfkwtz/react-native-picker-select it also appears to be working the way you want. Perhaps you have some logic that is overriding the back behavior...

Comment: i'm so sorry, this is not the package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker 
this is the one

Comment: The package you are using looks to be no longer maintained. Last release was in Oct 2016. I would suggest you use the 'react-native' picker.